# Can one retrieve a socket's port from the Linux Kernel data type `struct sock`?

Tags: sockets, linux-kernel, kprobe

**Motivation**

I'm trying to write a bpftrace program to trace out when a socket is ready for reading by hooking into the kprobe `sock_def_readable`. I will get a `struct sock` to inspect. I'd like to map it back to the socket I created in user-land.

**Question**

How does one recover the port number from a `struct sock`?

Comment: It would be astonishing if it wasn't in there. Have you considered looking at the definition?

Comment: I think I can use the `inet_sk(sk)->inet_sport` or `inet_sk(sk)->inet_dport` functions to do it.

Comment: Which kernel version do you use?

Comment: @red0ct I think 4.15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just expanded the definition of `inet_sk` ... which was merely a cast.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bpftrace

#include <linux/net/inet_sock.h>

BEGIN
{
    printf("network tracing");
}

kprobe:sock_def_readable
{
  $inet_sock = (struct inet_sock *)arg0;
  printf("sock_def_readable destination port %d, source port %d \n", $inet_sock->inet_sport, $inet_sock->inet_dport);
}
```

Comment: An annoying thing is the ports are in big endian